# filter item with checkbox through array

Tags: ecmascript-6

[image]I have a checkbox that chooses everyone. And I have a checkbox that returns the systemi object. And I have a checkbox that returns the charteri object. But there is a problem with this one. And does not give us the checkbox information.
I want to click on the systeme ckeckbox. Only the information about it will be displayed to us.
I want to click on the charteri ckeckbox. Only the information about it will be displayed to us.

In fact, we want to return the object through systemi or charteri.

We have several filters. It should be as if several filters were activated. Filtering done.

```js
function customFilter(list, field, value) {
        let fill = list.filter(task => {
            if (typeof(filter) === 'Object') {
                value.forEach(val => {
                    return task[field] === value
                });
            }
            return task[field] === value
        });
        console.log(fill);

    }

    let filterCheckbox = document.querySelector('.customCheck');
    filter_ch.addEventListener('change', filt);

    function filt(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var
            //field = $(this).parents('.filter_type').attr('data-field');
  let field =document.querySelector('.filter_type').getAttribute('data-field');

        let val = e.target.value;
        customFilter(FlyList, field, val);
    };
```

```html
<div class="filter_type" data-field="flkind">
    <h6>Ticket type
        <div class="switcher float-left ">
            <label class="customToggle small">
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="selectall">
                all
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </h6>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label class="customCheck " id="filter-check">
                <input type="checkbox" value={systemi} name="inlineRadioOptions" data-field="systemi" class="individual"> systemi
                <div class="indicator"></div>
                <span class="float-left">
                air2
               </span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="customCheck" id="filter-check2" >
                <input type="checkbox" value={charteri} name="inlineRadioOptions" data-field="charteri" class="individual"> charteri
                <div class="indicator"></div>
                <span class="float-left">
               air2
               </span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul> </div>
```

```js
let FlyList = [{
 "id": "1",
 "city": "Dallas",
 "capacity": "1",
 "time": "06:00",
 "fltime": "07:00",
 "price": "10000",
 "flnum": "961",
 "pricetest": "dd",
 "flkind": "systemi"
}, {
 "id": "2",
 "city": "Bevery Hills",
 "capacity": "2",
 "time": "14:00",
 "fltime": "15:00",
 "price": "20000",
 "flnum": "960",
 "pricetest": '',
 "flkind": "systemi"
}, {
 "id": "3",
 "city": "New York",
 "capacity": "3",
 "time": "04:00",
 "fltime": "05:00",
 "price": "30000",
 "flnum": "950",
 "flkind": "systemi"
},
];
```

Comment: You cannot `return` from a `forEach` callback.

Comment: So what should i do? How do I fix the code?

Comment: Write your own method.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve in there, but you might be looking for `return value.some(…)` instead

Comment: We can not return a few items in this way.